# Ogr2ogr: Shape to MySQL. Delete (or ignore) "geometry_columns" and "spatial_ref_sys"

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, mysql

I'm exporting a shapefile to my MySQL database. But as standard it also add the additional metadata tables: 
"geometry_columns" and "spatial_ref_sys"

Is there a way to either delete these tables or don't export them to the database, in the some ogr2ogr job? Of course I can always delete them after, but it would be so nice if they are just ignored from the start.

My code is:

```
ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:database,host=localhost,user=user,password=code /TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp -nln Projects -update -overwrite -lco engine=MYISAM
```

Comment: It should be possible to drop tables with ogrinfo by using a command like `ogrinfo MySQL:database,host=localhost,user=user,password=code -sql "drop table geometry_columns"`

Comment: Nice. that works